# Does gravitational pull depend on the velocity of movement?

Tags: general-relativity

In classical mechanics the gravitational pull doesn't depend on the velocity. It's the same regardless if the body stands still or moves.

In general relativity, the test particles follow geodesics and the "coordinate acceleration" described by the geodesic equation:

[image]

The rate of change of coordinate velocity depends on the coordinate velocity on right side. Basically the $\Gamma$s say what coordinate acceleration corresponds to a given input vector.

Of course this velocity is four velocity which has a constant length $c$, so any change of it must be orthogonal to it, so it makes sense that the rate of change must have some dependency on the current vector. But in 3+1 dimensions there are more degrees of freedom.

So the question: does GR allow velocity dependent gravitational pull? If not can you show why not?

Comment: How big is the mass involved that's moving? If a body moves fast enough in GR or SR, as you know, it will gain mass and increase its gravitational pull wrt other bodies.

Comment: @AcidJazz There is no "relativistic mass" in GR. Also only the space-time curvature depends on the masses of the bodies making it, but the test particles with negligble masses "riding" it won't affect it.

Comment: Can you clarify what equation you are citing? Your equation looks like the geodesic equation, but it should have $d\tau$ on the bottom not $dt$. It is possible to [write the geodesic equation using coordinate time](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geodesics_in_general_relativity#Equivalent_mathematical_expression_using_coordinate_time_as_parameter), but the result is more complicated than what you cite.

Comment: Also, are you asking if the norm of the four-acceleration is independent of the four-velocity, or whether the three acceleration measured in the momentary rest frame is independent of velocity, or something else?

Comment: Thanks for that, I follow your second point, although would you mind explaining a bit more about the difference in GR and SR, with respect to relativistic mass, or tell me a source? Seriously,  it's genuinely important for me to understand the difference and avoid my usual mistake, making quick assumptions. I can ask it as a separate question otherwise. Thanks very much

Comment: @AcidJazz: have a read through [the results from this search](http://physics.stackexchange.com/search?q=relativistic+mass). Note that relativistic mass is a deprecated concept in both SR and GR. It is not the case that relativistic mass is a useful concept in one but not the other.

Comment: @JohnRennie thanks John, I will do that, can I push my luck here a bit more, just a yes or no will do. As far as I know, Potential Energy is not a useful or relevant concept in relativity. I did ask a question related to this earlier and got told no, just want to nail it once  and for all and stop thinking locally. then I will look at terms in stress energy tensor again. Much obliged.

Comment: @AcidJazz: for a time independent metric there is a conserved quantity that is basically total energy. However splitting it into kinetic and potential parts is observer dependant and rarely a useful thing to do.

Comment: @JohnRennie Okay, replaced $t$ with $\tau$.

Comment: @Calmarius: but it still isn't clear what you are asking. I would guess you are asking if the four-acceleration is independent of the four-velocity? Is this so?

Comment: @JohnRennie Maybe coordinate time expression is better afterall. Imagine you are distant observer looking the black hole at the galactic center and you set some polar coordinate system around this black hole, and you plot the star positions around it. And based on the data you also have the coordiante velocity and coordinate acceleration. The question is: Is the observed acceleration depend on the observed velocity? 
But based on that Wikipedia article you linked it seems that's exactly the case.

Comment: This is a gauge-dependent question with, unsurprisingly, a gauge-dependent answer. For example let's say I am in the weak field limit. Then the gravitational acceleration of a freely falling particle in the background global inertial frame has a gravitomagnetic component that involves the coupling of the particle's velocity to the gravitomagnetic field. But I can go to a background rotating frame suitably chosen to eliminate the gravitomagnetic term thereby removing this velocity dependent gravitational acceleration. It's really no different from the usual velocity dependent Coriolis force.

Comment: You could Lorentz transform the entire metric if it is in constant velocity (usually is). Then substitute that metric into the geodesic equations. If it is not in constant velocity and is instead moving due to a gravitational field itself (e.g. N-body problems) then it is slightly harder to do.